# How to get SUM of values in cosmos db

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How do you get the sum of multiple values in cosmos db:
Data example:

```
[
 {nr:1},
 {nr:5}
]
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT VALUE SUM(c.nt)
FROM c
```

Expected response:
`6`

What i have tried:
Query:

```sql
SELECT VALUE SUM(c._ts)
FROM c
```

Result:
`no result`

If I try the same query but with COUNT it works.
The only aggregates that do not work are SUM and AVG.

Code snippet:

```
String query = "SELECT VALUE SUM(c._ts) FROM c";
CosmosPagedFlux<Integer> fuxResponse = container.queryItems(
      query,
      new CosmosQueryRequestOptions(),
      Integer.class
    );
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      fuxResponse
        .byPage(1)
        .flatMap(
          fluxResponse -> {
            data.addAll(fluxResponse.getResults());
            return Flux.empty();
          }
        )
        .blockLast();
    } catch (Exception err) {}
```

After the code runs data is an empty array.

Comment: The query should work if you have _ts values in your collection

Comment: I know it should work but it does not work. That is why i am asking here. It does not make any sence that it does not work.

Comment: it might be an issue with your logic, change the type as string and see

Comment: `select value sum(c.nr) from c` works - I just tried it. Note that above in your code, you have `sum (c.nt)`, not `sum(c.nr)`. Maybe it's just a typo? Also: `select value sum(c._ts)` is going to add up the value of the timestamps - is that what you want, or are you trying to do a count (e.g. `select value count(c._ts)`?